# Variable does not exist: hed__End_Date__c

Tags: apex, class, variable

```
public class UpdateGraduated {
    public static void WhenGraduatedUpdate(List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> enrollmentListUpdate){
        try{
            List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> enrollmentList = new List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c>();
            List<contact> contactList = new List<contact>();
            List<contact> contactListUpdated = new List<contact>();
            set<id> IdList = new set<Id>();
            enrollmentList = [select id, hed__Contact__c , hed__Enrollment_Status__c, hed__End_Date__c
                             from hed__Program_Enrollment__c
                             where id in:enrollmentListUpdate
                             and hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Graduated'];

            for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c en: enrollmentList) {
                IdList.add(en.hed__Contact__c);
            }

            contactList = [select id, Graduation_Date__c from contact where id in : IdList];

            for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c enn: enrollmentList) {
                for(contact en :contactList){
                    if(enn.hed__Contact__c == en.id && enn.hed__Enrollment_Status__c == 'Graduated'){
                        en.hed__End_Date__c = enn.Graduation_Date__c;
                        contactListUpdated.add(en);
                    }
                }
            }
            update contactListUpdated;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            system.debug('Error is -> '+ e.getMessage() + 'at Line -> '+ e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on Line 22 of my Apex class that a variable `hed_End_Date__c` does not exist but the field does exist in my production and sandbox. So I am not 100% sure where I am going wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Realised my problem! The assignment needs to be the other way around.

Instead of :

```
en.hed__End_Date__c = enn.Graduation_Date__c;
```

It should be:

```
en.Graduation_Date__c = enn.hed__End_Date__c;
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't forget to accept your answer. This way the question will be marked as solved and it will not be randomly bumped to homepage in a few months/years

Comment: @Novarg Thanks,  how do I 'accept' my answer?

Comment: you have a tick/check mark on the left side(under the score). Click it and it will turn green, meaning that this is an accepted answer